# Mean value theorem, second derivative, in $\mathbf{R}^n$.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Why is the following statement true:

Suppose that $f$ is twice continuously differentiable on open set $U \subset \mathbf{R}^n$. Then for all $x, y \in U$ there exists $t \in [0, 1]$ such that $z = x + t(y - x)$ and such that 
$$
f(y) = f(x) + \langle \nabla f(x), y- x \rangle + (1/2) \langle y - x, \nabla^2f(z)(y-x)\rangle. 
$$

It vaguely looks like an application of the mean value theorem, but I can't seem to show it.

Comment: Simply open sets does not work. It requires that the set $ \{x + t(y-x): t \in [0,1]\} \subset U$ at least. Consider reducing this to the Taylor formula in 1-dimensional case. Put $F(t) = f(x + t(y-x)), t \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: Sure, it should be open and connected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### General domains

The claim is false for a general open connected set $U$. For a counterexample, let $U=\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{(x_1, 0):x_1\ge 0\}$ be a slit plane. Define
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} x_1^3\quad &\text{if }x_1,x_2>0\\  0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
This is a twice continuously differentiable function: e.g., the second derivative in the $x_1$ direction is 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 6x_1\quad &\text{if }x_1,x_2>0\\  0 &\text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$
which is continuous in $U$. The other second partials are identically zero.

Choose $x=(1, -1)$ and $y=(1, 1)$. Then the claim takes the form 
$$
1 = (1/2) \langle y - x, \nabla^2f(z)(y-x)\rangle = 2 \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x_2^2}(z) = 0
$$
which is false.

---

#### Convex domains

The correct statement would assume that $U$ is open and **convex**, not merely connected. Then the proof follows by considering the function $g(t) = f(x+t(y-x))$ of a real variable $t\in [0, 1]$ and applying Taylor's theorem with the [Lagrange form of the remainder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder).